# Expo project android emulator issue

Tags: react-native, android-emulator, expo

I've been working on a react-native app managed mode built on expo, I was working from a mac at first which worked perfectly fine using the IOS simulator it didn't work on android emulator on mac, here i switched to a windows computer and the issue still exists on the android emulator, **executing the command "expo start" the app crashes after the splash screen before the logo appears**, I tested the app on a real device on the debug mode and it worked! also after deploying the apk file the app works with no issues, the only problem is it's not working on android simulator using expo client, things i tried to solve the issue including trying to reinstall android studio and install the latest version, tried updating expo sdk to latest version also tried playing around with the app.js from where the app launches the first time but still crashes at the same point, **it's not showing any errors or warning it just crashes**, any suggestion or something i could try would be very helpful thanks.

[image: Expo diagnostics]